# In DNN 9, Pages Move to End of Menu After Page Settings are Updated

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Recently began developing with DNN 9.01.01. I've noticed that any time I update the page settings for a given page, it moves the location to the end of the menu for the level that it's in. For example, I always have a Home page that's the leftmost menu item. After I save the Page Settings, it becomes the rightmost menu item. If it's the at the top of a submenu, it gets sent to the bottom.

I'm not sure if this is a Razor issue, an issue with the skins I've been developing, or if this is an issue with DNN 9. This issue does occur when using the default skin.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem on 9.0.1.

Comment: I currently have 7 websites from running 9.0.1 that each have the issue.

Comment: Do they all have that skin?

Comment: They do not. In fact, the default DNN skin has the issue as well. So, 7 skins I've developed along with the default skin all have the issue. I'm thinking it may not be a skin issue for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that problem.

I didn't see it in Jira so I reported it.  It's DNN Platform DNN-10495, or https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-10495?filter=-4

Comment: Thank you for confirming and reporting.

Comment: Noting here that the issue is fixed in DNN 9.2